# Error with creating a equation in ADS with the variable already defined on the schematic as Var

Tags: diagram, ads, equation

I am trying to create a equation to plot the eye diagram from the voltage node Vout

As I define the equation, it tells me that the "Tbit" is not defined!?

I wonder why because I have already defined it on the schematic in the 'Var" icon

Does anyone know?
[image]
[image]